# Netbeans 7.1 - how to double-click to select a word?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I am used to double-click to select a word. I am addicted to using double-click to select a word. Almost everywhere it is there - eg, notepad,Gnome-edit, ...

Would please someone help me how do I set this functionality ?

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "set"? It works "out of the box", no need to setup anything

Comment: I've found out that it works by using an extremely high rate of double-click. I am too surprised why are such events occurring. It seems strange that the normal double-click rate works normally outside Netbeans.

Comment: I dont think thats it - I think its a regular rate, but if your used to "double-click" then drag the selection to get more, it does not do the inital selection.  In other words, it selects with the doubleclick (after you click-click[release]), but not if you do (click-click-[hold or start moving the caret])

Comment: https://www.netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=89607 bug for my comment - maybe they fixed it in 6.8, and its back in 7.

Comment: It does work out of the box for me in Netbeans 7 and dont remember it ever not working

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bug of a specific NetBeans editor module, not an option you can set. For example, in NetBeans 7.4 the selection works all right (selecting the whole word) for PHP and JS files I'm working with, but not all right only for TPL files (HTML/JS/Smarty variables and values in TPL files), which are managed by the Smarty Framework plugin.